# Conditionally deploying AWS Config rules using cdk python

Tags: python, aws-cdk, aws-config

I have a requirement to deploy config rules conditionally based on certain parameters.  Here below is one

```
config.ManagedRule(self, "AccessKeysRotated",
    identifier=config.ManagedRuleIdentifiers.ACCESS_KEYS_ROTATED,
    input_parameters={
        "max_access_key_age": 60
    },
    maximum_execution_frequency=config.MaximumExecutionFrequency.TWELVE_HOURS
)
```

Here below is another one

```
config.ManagedRule(self, "S3BucketLogging",
    identifier=config.ManagedRuleIdentifiers.S3_BUCKET_LOGGING_ENABLED,
    config_rule_name="S3BucketLogging"
)
```

The managed rule identifiers are in the hundreds. I don't want to have all of these in one big file but each rule stored in a separate file. I can then read off a dynamodb where I store the account name and a csv list of rules that pertain to that account. Each item in the csv can be a single file which has a single rule. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  Create a `aws_config_stack`, which you deploy once per account/region pair.

In the constructor, get the environment's rule names from DynamoDB with a `get_item` SDK call. The `boto3` command gets called at synth-time, which is keeping with [CDK best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps-synth).

Define the rules in whatever files you want.  Wrap each rule in a function that accepts a scope and returns the rule:

```py
# make_access_keys_rotated_rule.py
# One function per ManagedRule.  Add to the rule dictionary.  Called by `make_rule`
def make_access_keys_rotated_rule(scope: Construct) -> config.ManagedRule:
    return config.ManagedRule(scope, "AccessKeysRotated",
        identifier=config.ManagedRuleIdentifiers.ACCESS_KEYS_ROTATED,
        input_parameters={
            "max_access_key_age": 60
        },
        maximum_execution_frequency=config.MaximumExecutionFrequency.TWELVE_HOURS
    )
```

Add each rule function to a dictionary, where the keys are the rule name.  Perhaps add the dictionary lookup logic to a method in your `aws_config_stack` subclass.  A `make_rule` method looks up the rule-making function by name and executes it, adding a single rule to the stack.

```py
# aws_config_stack.py method
# Look up and execute a ManagedRule function by rule name.  Called in the constructor.
def make_rule(self: Construct, rule_name: str) -> config.ManagedRule:
    rule_dict = {
        "AccessKeysRotated": make_access_keys_rotated_rule
    }

    return rule_dict[rule_name](self)
```

Finally, in the stack constructor, call `make_rule` for every name in the rule-name list from DynamoDB.

```py
# aws_config_stack.py constructor
rules: list[config.ManagedRule] = [self.make_rule(r) for r in rule_names_from_dynamo]
```

After synth, a `cdk diff` should reveal rules being added and deleted from the stack to match the list from DynamoDB.

P.S. Optionally add the Delivery Channel (`CfnDeliveryChannel` + `Bucket`) resources and Configuration Recorder (`CfnConfigurationRecorder` + `Role`) resources to the same stack to have the CDK fully manage the AWS Config resources.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to python, so this might be a basic question. How does the main file which holds the aws_config_stack know of the individual files which contain the rules enclosed in a function? Is there a file include involved somewhere? Would that mean I would have to have 100s of includes for each function enclosed in its own file?

Comment: @user20358 Yes, you need to [import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) the rules to give the stack access to them.  There are lots of approaches, as a SO search for [python import all](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+import+all) reveals.

Comment: Thanks. In the `make_rule` method once I return a particular set of rules in `rule_dict`. How do I execute a rule in the dict? Not looking at iterating thru a loop, but the part how the code within the dict is executed to create a rule in config

Comment: @user20358 The `make_rule` method adds a single rule (by name) to the stack.  It is calling the `make_x_rule` functions that are in the dict (see the `return` line).  The next block's [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-and-similar-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i) syntax calls `make_rule` once for each rule name in a list, adding rules to the stack.  Note: I edited the answer to add explanations and to fix an error in `make_rule`'s signature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a config file strategy instead if you would prefer. Similar to the answer by @fedonev, you can create a json file that holds the information for a particular set of rules. Then you can add conditionals before and a loop around loading the json file. Then you can use a trick of python and the fact that every one of these properties is a kwarg, and kwargs are dictionary.

Something like:

json_file:

```
{   
    "AccessKeysRotated": {
           "identifier": "ACCESS_KEYS_ROTATED",
           "input_parameters": {
                "max_access_key_age": 60
           },
           "maximum_execution_frequency": "TWELVE_HOURS"
     }
}
```

and then you load this into a python dict using json.loads.

you'll need to update the Enum values to the same classes, luckily the names can be used for that:

```py
if "identifier" in your_config.keys():
    your_config["identifier"] = config.ManagedRuleIdentifiers(your_config["identifier"])
```

(that can be done a lot more elegantly, but you mentioned in a comment your new to python so that is fine for now)

and finally, the trick: Because every property on a CDK object is a kwarg (keyword argument) and kwargs are stored as  a dictionary behind the scenes, and have default values (thats what defines them as kwargs) you can - even with different keys - use:

```py
## load json files that you need into a dict of dict objects
## make sure the enum values are updated from strings to enums

for key, config_setting in my_configs.items():
    config.ManagedRule(self, key, **config_setting)
```

the key being the logical id of the object (so the "AccessKeysRotated" in your json file) and the ** syntax merging the dictionary of kwargs with the defaults. Because it merges your input second (its basically `kwargs = {**kwargs, **config_setting}` your values override any defaults in the kwarg dict and boom. done.

Some tweaking will be needed undoubtedly, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: Thanks. Where can I find the json files for each of the managed rules?

Comment: also, when calling `config.ManagedRule(,,)` The parameter you are suggesting is a json object of the rule created from the json file right? That is not accepted.

Comment: They would have to be something you create yourself. They do not exist normally, but would be a solution you could craft on your own if you so wished.